# jBPM6 not persisting boundary timers

Tags: timer, jbpm

I have a jBPM process setup with a boundary timer on a human task set for 30s (for testing purposes) - this is to escalate to another task if the time expires.

This normally functions correctly - when the task is reached and 30s are up, the flow is moved to the next task.

However, if I bounce the server, it seems that none of the timers are recreated and the flow sits on that task indefinitely.

The chances of the server being bounced in the real world are fairly high, as the timeouts will be more likely to last a couple of days.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

How are you executing your process, using the execution server as part of jbpm-console or embedding the engine yourself?

If you are embedding the engine yourself, note that you need to reinitialize your RuntimeManager upon restart (don't wait on the first request to do this, as this won't reactivate timers).